# Java script takes too much time to finish

Tags: java, performance, time, brute-force

I don't know how to make my code less time consuming. My task was to make brute force password break. I knew how long password is and which characters it contains. So far i have this method.

```
    public boolean moznosti(char [] arr, String pr, int a, int b) {
    if (b == 0) {
        char [] heslo = pr.toCharArray();
        if(tryOpen(heslo)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }    
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
            String tmp = pr+arr[i];
            if (moznosti(arr, tmp, a, b-1) == false) {
                return false;
            }
            moznosti(arr, tmp, a, b-1);
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

where heslo is password. any ideas?

Comment: I believe your question is better suited for [StackExchange Code Review Q&A](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Recursive function => usually slower; try to do an iterative solution and see how that work. I second @Aziz. This should go to Code Review.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at your code structure.

You have a for loop which recursively calls your moznosti method, and each time it's called it doing the same thing.

I don't know what your variables mean but assuming a and b are 4. Your first cycle will call your moznosti method 4 times with the same b parameter.

Not that this is causing the time issue but where you have:

```
if (moznosti(arr, tmp, a, b-1) == false)
```

Because the moznosti method returns a Boolean value, you don't need to check if it's equal to false or true, the if statement brackets only pass when the condition is true. So in your case this might be more applicable:

```
if (!moznosti(arr, tmp, a, b-1))
```

I think the part which is taking most of the time is where you are checking your base case

```
if (moznosti(arr, tmp, a, b-1) == false)
```

Comment: Well, a simple boolean check wouldn't be causing as much harm as a recursive function call.

Comment: I think that would be more suited as a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

Okay i did it!

```
public class BruteForceAttacker extends Thief {
private boolean konec;

@Override
public void breakPassword(int sizeOfPassword) {
    moznosti(getCharacters(), "", getCharacters().length, sizeOfPassword);       
}

public void moznosti(char [] arr, String pr, int a, int b) {
    if (konec != true) {
        if (b == 0) {
            char [] heslo = pr.toCharArray();
            if (tryOpen(heslo)) {
                konec = true;
            } 
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
                String tmp = pr+arr[i];
                moznosti(arr, tmp, a, b-1);
        }
    }
}
```

}